# Swift JSON variables with all numeric names. What's the work around?

Tags: json, swift, naming-conventions, decodable

I am pulling some JSON data that I need to parse using Decodable into Swift.

As most of the data is dates I have 365 date entries along the lines of:

```
"20170101": 0.17, 
"20170102": 1.0, 
"20170103": 0.68, 
"20170104": 0.61, 
"20170105": 1.03, 
"20170106": 0.48, 
"20170107": 0.52, 
"20170108": 0.51, 
"20170109": 0.28,
```

When I am generating the relevant struct to absorb the data how to I create a variable with a what appears to be a numeric name:

```
var 20170101: Double
```

What, and is there, a workaround to having a numeric name?

Comment: You should store the data as `Dictionary<Date:Double>` and parse the keys as `Dates` rather than store them as `Double`'s.

Comment: That makes complete sense - will pursue. Many thanks.

Comment: please provide an answer if @DávidPásztor comment worked out i would like to learn how to use it  many thanks

Comment: you can't name your vars starting with numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You' re not allowed to use digits as first letter of properties name. But sometimes we have to use digits as you've shown in your code.

Solution of that problem is using CodingKey protocol with Enumerations like below:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case date = "20170101" // You can use "date" instead of "20170101".
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable names can’t begin with a number (although you can use numbers later in the name). They must start with a letter or an underscore `_`:

```
var _20170101: Double
var d20170101: Double
var d_20170101: Double
```

In Swift (as with other languages) variable names cannot contain whitespace characters, mathematical symbols (such as the plus (+) or minus (-) operators) or certain Unicode values or line and [box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).The main reason for this is to ensure that the Swift compiler is able understand where the names of our variables start and where they finish.

Other than that, when naming a variable:

- Strive for clarity
- Prioritize clarity over brevity
- Name variables, parameters, and associated types according to their roles

For more details on naming conventions, have a look [here](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming).

Comment: That's a bad idea. Keys as string representations of dates in a JSON response are clearly dynamic, so you cannot generate variable names based on those. This is exactly what collections are for.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking why they can't have a "*numeric name*"

Comment: OP is clearly asking for a workaround, since that's explicitly stated in the question.  Moreover, the question clearly involves JSON as well, not just a naming convention, so simply stating how to include numbers in variable names is not a good answer IMHO. Also, in my experience when numbers are involved in variable names, more often than not those variables shouldn't exist on their own but should be elements of a collection.

Comment: I see what you're saying. This answers this part of the question "*how to I create a variable with a what appears to be a numeric name*". If you feel this is a slimy answer you can downvote it if you deem appropriate. Or better, offer the questioner an answer with the way you understand their question.

Comment: @Carpsen90 are you suggesting OP to have a struct with 365 properties?

Comment: @LeoDabus You already know the answer to that. That's not what the OP is asking, as far as I understand their main question: "*What, and is there, a workaround to having a **numeric name**?*".

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your json dictionary as `[String:Double]` and them convert it to a tuple array of date and double:

```
let json = """
{
"20170101": 0.17,
"20170102": 1.0,
"20170103": 0.68,
"20170104": 0.61,
"20170105": 1.03,
"20170106": 0.48,
"20170107": 0.52,
"20170108": 0.51,
"20170109": 0.28
}
"""
```

---

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

---

```
do {
    let array: [(date: Date, double: Double)] = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Double].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
        .compactMap({ key, value in
        guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: key) else { return nil }
        return (date, value)
    }).sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
    for (date, double) in array {
        print("Date:", dateFormatter.string(from: date), "• Value:", double)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

> Date: 20170101 • Value: 0.17
>
> Date: 20170102 • Value: 1.0
>
> Date: 20170103 • Value: 0.68
>
> Date: 20170104 • Value: 0.61
>
> Date: 20170105 • Value: 1.03
>
> Date: 20170106 • Value: 0.48
>
> Date: 20170107 • Value: 0.52
>
> Date: 20170108 • Value: 0.51
>
> Date: 20170109 • Value: 0.28

Answer (score 0):

I lack the time to do a coded answer now, but in the mean time you might try to parse your dictionary as `[Date:Double` in an initializer and set

```
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy
```

in your `JSONDecoder`. I am not sure if `dateDecodingStrategy` will apply to keys, but it seems worth a try. Check out [this post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/) for more details on how to do `dateDecodingStrategy`.